# Changes in bash_profile not reflecting in command line

Tags: bash, command-line

I had hacked together some basic configuration in my .bash_profile to include git completion and some color changes in my command prompt.

I just reinstalled linux mint 18.2 and added the .bash_profile file from back up.

It works fine when i run the below command but only last the current session.

```
. .bash_profile
```

here is the code from .bash_profile

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default
.profile

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
source ~/.git-completion.bash;
export PS1='\[\033[1;33m\]\W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") $\[\033[0m\] '
LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=1;91:fi=0;96:'
export LS_COLORS
fi
```

Also from my .profile i see the .bashrc file is being loaded. Should i include the file in .bashrc?

Comment: Have a careful look at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files -- bash will use .bash_profile or .profile but not both. Does your terminal start a login shell or not?

Comment: Hey Glenn, thanks for the link. I just added the if statement in my bash_profile to the end of the bashrc file. Its working perfect now.